# How to copy a workspace of a job from jenkins master to slave container and copy back from slave to master?

Tags: docker, jenkins, containers

For me both Jenkins master and slave are running on docker container. I have workspace of a job on master that is build before calling a slave(Linux docker container). I want to copy the workspace of master's job to my slave container because that files in that workspace will be used in further execution.

And After successfully execution on slave container, it will generate number of log files, that i want to copy back to Jenkins master for sending the reports as emails.

PS: Jenkins master and slave both are running smoothly. slave container is created by configuring images and other required settings in docker template.

I am naive in Jenkins and docker containers, I have no clue how can i achieve this. Please give some suggestion to achieve this. thank you all for efforts and suggestions in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Typically you will not share workspaces to exchange files/build artifacts between Build agents, but you will use "Buil Artifacts".

You can either do this via Jenkins Pipeline Script. See the `archiveArtifacts` step in the following example: https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/tour/tests-and-artifacts/

Now you can either copy the artifacts in your next build stage, or if it is another build Job you can use the [Copy Artifact Plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/copyartifact/) for Jenkins.

The Artifacts you will save do not need to be "Build Artifacts", but can be any file within yur workspace. So you e.g. could also archive test files which you will use in a later step.

Comment: Thank You @A.K. your solution has worked half for me like I am able to copy from master to slave using copy artifact. but after execution on slave, it will generate logs and some other files. how can I send these log etc from slave container to master. the moment container finished its execution, it will be killed and the workspace of container will be deleted immediately. How can I save/copy the slave container workspace for report purpose?

Comment: You can also archive the artifacts (report logs) on the slave. They will then show up in the job overview (when it's finished) and automatically stored on the amster node. If the reports can be parsed by a plugin (e.g. https://plugins.jenkins.io/tap/) you can also add the parsing of the logs as a step after ypour build on the slave node.

Comment: Super,
one more thing, where will the archived artifact will be store? and how can i access it?

Comment: Please look at the documentation about how to use Archive Artifact/Copy Artifact for Jenkins. https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/copyartifact/ https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/core/  https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/tour/tests-and-artifacts/ This will answer most of your questions. If you have some more specific questions/problems with your solution you can still ask.